# Sort posts using ACF/post_meta date field, if none set, use post date

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

Hoping someone can help me!

So i’ve created a custom post type, and assigned a date/time selector do it.

I have altered the loop to include my custom post type, and want to sort so that if a date is set to a post, then it sorts by that date selected in the loop. If not, then should just use the post date (and this is true for all other posts).

I don’t want to filter just posts with this set, i want all posts. it’s essentially artifically changing the post_date to be the one set in custom field.

I need to do this as the dates are ahead in time.

Hope someone can help me!

i’ve checked the fields output date, again the post date and the format is identical (2019-04-03 17:00:00).

**Unlike all the rest of the questions on this topic, i don't want to put the items with the meta meta first.**

UPDATED

```
function add_tours_to_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'tours') );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_tours_to_query' );
```

So you have:

```
Blog Post - 2/04/2019
Tour Post with post meta set date of 3/04/2019
Blog Post 4/04/2019
Blog post 5/04/2019
```

In that order

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share the code of your template? The loop you altered?

Comment: I am trying to understand... you want all the normal posts AND your custom 'tours' posts, ordered by date set in ACF?

Comment: No so i want the standard loop to run with the blog posts by their post dates. Then for the tours posts, if a custom field with a date is set, order it into the standard loop by that date. - Updated post again

Comment: run two queries 1 to find tours with date and one to find standard posts then join the arrays ordered by date and output the results